# Mysql Access denied using Laravel Forge and Digital Ocean

Tags: mysql, laravel

Please help. All of a sudden around 2019-01-24 06:37:10 UTC I started receiving errors on my server that:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm unable to access mysql. I did not change anything on my end, so I don't know what happened. When I look through the system logs, I do see some mysql activity around that time:

```
Jan 24 06:36:07 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Jan 24 06:36:24 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767450.357697] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=32:f4:a6:e9:03:29:f0:4b:3a:4e:50:30:08:00 SRC=85.10.193.56 DST=206.189.227.234 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=37186 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57178 DPT=22123 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Jan 24 06:36:32 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopping Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopping Daily apt download activities.
Jan 24 06:36:33 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Jan 24 06:36:38 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 24 06:36:38 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 06:36:42 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 24 06:36:42 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 24 06:36:46 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767472.035497] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311806.292:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=27468 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 24 06:36:46 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767472.069261] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311806.324:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=27486 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 06:36:46 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767472.132572] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311806.388:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=27501 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 06:36:50 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767476.078756] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311810.336:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=27552 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 06:36:53 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767478.885369] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311813.140:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=27601 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan 24 06:36:53 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: message repeated 5 times: [ Reloading.]
Jan 24 06:36:53 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 06:36:53 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767479.454427] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311813.708:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=27677 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 06:36:53 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767479.499368] audit: type=1400 audit(1548311813.756:45): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=27682 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=113 ouid=0
Jan 24 06:36:54 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Can someone help me understand if something in that system log is what caused the problem? How can I fix it? This is our production server and I can not access the database. Neither can our application. Not good.

I see these upgrades occurred automatically at that time. These must be causing the issue:

```
Start-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:21
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: mysql-client-5.7:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
End-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:22

Start-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:25
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: mysql-client-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
End-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:26

Start-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:38
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: mysql-server-5.7:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2), mysql-server-core-5.7:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
End-Date: 2019-01-24  06:36:54
```

I ran these commands as per one of the comments:

```
ufw status
ufw allow 3306
```

This did not seem to help. Here's the current output of `ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When I restart mysql on a working development server, I get this output in the syslog:

```
Jan 24 13:08:16 smooth-star systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 13:08:17 smooth-star systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 24 13:08:17 smooth-star systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 13:08:17 smooth-star kernel: [4733737.407768] audit: type=1400 audit(1548335297.764:31): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=28433 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 13:08:17 smooth-star kernel: [4733737.456162] audit: type=1400 audit(1548335297.812:32): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=28438 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=113 ouid=0
Jan 24 13:08:18 smooth-star systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

On the production server, which has the issue, I get this when restarting mysql:

```
Jan 24 13:10:40 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane kernel: [ 8114.162705] kauditd_printk_skb: 6 callbacks suppressed
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane kernel: [ 8114.162707] audit: type=1400 audit(1548335441.898:130): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=6841 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane kernel: [ 8114.186619] audit: type=1400 audit(1548335441.922:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=6841 comm="mysqld" capability=2  capname="dac_read_search"
Jan 24 13:10:41 whispering-hurricane kernel: [ 8114.217354] audit: type=1400 audit(1548335441.954:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=6850 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=113 ouid=0
Jan 24 13:10:42 whispering-hurricane systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Is something in here causing the problem?

Comment: Check if you are using the right `password` to connect to your `mysql` instance

Comment: I am. I created a new user with a new password as well, but that won't work.

Comment: Forge is paid environment. You should check with support.

Comment: I have this issue myself. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @FelipePeña Following these steps is the only thing that worked for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-18-04. I still have no idea what happened. It's clearly a result of an auto-update that Forge ran, but no one will take responsibility for it. So I'm basically just hoping it doesn't happen again, and if it does, I'll follow the steps in that article again.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to confirm:

You have generated a key using `php artisan key:generate`?

This key is in your `.env` file under a `APP_KEY` key?

Your `config/app.php` has a key `'key' => env('APP_KEY')`?

If all of these are in place you should be right. Come back if there are any errors.

Comment: Yes that's all correct. I'm not even able to access mysql from the command line, so this is not a laravel-specific issue. Something changed on the Forge server and I now can't access mysql at all. I think it may have something to do with apparmor.

Comment: Ok I get you !! Are you able to SSH into your build? To test this, either SSH in or run a simple ‘pwd’ command followed by ‘ls’ make sure that your file your need you can get. You can set permission with sudo command

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't access the database might be due to `UFW` not allowing connection on your mysql port which I suppose is `3306`. Could you `SSH` into your forge server and type:

```
ufw status
ufw allow 3306
```

You might need `sudo permissions` for this. The reason for this thinking is this line in your logs:

```
...
Jan 24 06:36:24 whispering-hurricane kernel: [1767450.357697] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=32:f4:a6:e9:03:29:f0:4b:3a:4e:50:30:08:00 SRC=85.10.193.56 DST=206.189.227.234 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=37186 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57178 DPT=22123 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
...
```

Comment: I updated the question with the output of those commands. Please see above and let me know what you think. It did not seem to fix the problem.

Comment: okay, I found this article which explains the similar error you are encountering, could you check it out: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004185293-Unable-to-start-MySQL-on-Ubuntu-AVC-apparmor-DENIED-operation-open-

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I saw that as well but it did not fix the issue for some reason. I added some more info to the question if you can take a look.

Comment: It's certainly an issue with apparmor, he doesn't have access to read the audit files on your linux machine, it is a permission issue, but I'm sorry I don't know much about system administration so I can't help you with a concrete example on how to fix it :/